# Create daily option selector starting today, running one week

Tags: php

I am trying to create a HTML Option Selector using a PHP loop that starts (dynamically) from today with today's date and lists the next 6 days and their dates i.e.,

```
Thursday - 31/01/2019
Friday - 01/02/2019
Saturday - 02/02/2019
Sunday - 03/02/2019
Monday - 04/02/2019
Tuesday - 05/02/2019
Wednesday - 06/02/2019
```

I am trying to do it using a for loop and starting from today and adding one day to the Day and the Date, but currently the day is staying the same and I am getting 1970 dates (errors in my date logic)

Here's my code:

```
echo'<select id="select_day" name="select_day" class="form-control" required>';
echo'<option value=""Select Day</option>';
// output today as first option
$currentday = date("l");
$currentdate= date("d/m/Y");
  echo '<option value="'.$day.'">'.$currentday.' - '.$currentdate.'</option>';
  for ($i=1; $i<=6; $i++){
    $currentday = date("l", strtotime("+'.$i.' days"));
    $currentdate= date("d/m/Y", strtotime("+'.$i.' days"));
    echo '<option value="'.$day.'">'.$currentday.' - '.$currentdate.'</option>';
  }
echo'</select>';
```

Result:

```
<select id="select_day" name="select_day" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="">Select Day</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday - 31/01/2019</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday - 01/01/1970</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday - 01/01/1970</option>        
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday - 01/01/1970</option>        
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday - 01/01/1970</option>         
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday - 01/01/1970</option>        
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday - 01/01/1970</option>         
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change sigle qoute to double quote in 2 line at for loop

```
$currentday = date("l");
$currentdate= date("d/m/Y");
  echo $currentday.' - '.$currentdate;
  for ($i=1; $i<=6; $i++){
    $currentday = date("l", strtotime("+".$i." days"));
    $currentdate= date("d/m/Y", strtotime("+".$i." days"));
    echo $currentday.' - '.$currentdate;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated code:

```
echo'<select id="select_day" name="select_day" class="form-control" required>';
echo'<option value=""Select Day</option>';
// output today as first option
$currentday = date("l");
$currentdate= date("d/m/Y");
  echo '<option value="'.$currentdate.'">'.$currentday.' - '.$currentdate.'</option>';
  for ($i=1; $i<=6; $i++){
    $cday = date("l", strtotime("+" . $i ." days"));
    $cdate= date("d/m/Y", strtotime("+" . $i . " days"));
    echo '<option value="'.$cday.'">'.$cday.' - '.$cdate.'</option>';
  }
echo'</select>';
```